# how to join computer to domain through powershell

Tags: powershell

I have just done a fresh installation of windows 7 professional, and I would like to join my pc to domain through powershell but getting some error here is the code which I am using

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName HMD-PC002 -DomainName mydomain -Credential     
mydomain\Administrator

Add-Computer : Computer 'HMD-PC002' failed to join domain 'mydomain' from its current  
workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with
following error message: Unknown error (0xa8b).
At C:\Users\HMDPC002\Desktop\add-pc_to_Domain.ps1:8 char:1
+ Add-Computer -ComputerName HMD-PC002 -DomainName mydomain -Credential mydomain\A ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (HMD-PC002:String) [Add-Computer],   
InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :   
FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerComma
```

Answer (score 8):

There was an easy solution to this, i didnt configure my dns server i had to change it manually and after populating the two field i ran the following script and it worked

```
Add-Computer -DomainName mydomain -Credential mydomain\Administrator -Restart
```

However i want powershell to change the dns setting i will ask this in a separate question

Answer (score 2):

What i did before joining a server to domain:

1) Check the connectivity between DC and Server. Ping the domain controller. It should ping if both are on same subnet, else domain can't be joined.

2) Ran this powershell command:

PS C:\Windows\system32> add-computer domain.com -Credential domain\administrator
WARNING: The changes will take effect after you restart the computer SERVERNAME.

Answer (score 1):

As specified by you that it is already working script and from the error code and upon giving search it looks to be a problem with AD, please refer to the below link and try and see if it works by IP as suggested [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ab180b5d-ec0e-458c-a924-6a83b1758cba/join-w7-machine-to-w2003-existing-domain).